# angular $resourse pattern /messages/:id/:controller not working

Tags: angularjs

```
var User = $resource(
     '/s:userId/param:otherid',
    {
    userId: '@id',
    otherid:'@ids'
    }
    );

    User.get({
    id: '2',
    ids: '2'
    }, function(resp) {
     debugger
    }, function(err) {
    // Handle error here
    });
```

I want create request to adresses :

/s1/param1' or /s2/param2'

but in firebug network I see  request to adress **/s/param?id=2&ids=2**

Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the concept of the `$resource` url and verb expression. As stated in the **[$resource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)**:

> Each **key value** in the parameter object is first bound to **url template**
>   if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search
>   query after the ?.
>
> Given a template /path/:verb and parameter {verb:'greet',
>   salutation:'Hello'} results in URL /path/greet?salutation=Hello.

Since you're url has the following verbs: `:userId`, `:otherid`, then you're request object should look like this instead:

```
User.get({
  userId: '2',
  otherid: '2'
}, function(resp) {
 debugger
}, function(err) {
// Handle error here
});
```

Another misconception is the use of the `@` notation, the documentation states:

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that
>   parameter will be extracted from the **corresponding property on the
>   data object** (provided when calling an action method). For example,
>   if the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value
>   of someParam will be data.someProp.

The @ notation only applies to the instance action methods($get, $save, $query, etc..). Read the comments provided in the code below:

```
// Sends GET /s2/param2
User.get({
  userId: '2',
  otherid: '2'
}, function(resp) {

   // Let's assume the resp returns {id: 2, ids: 2}
   // Then the request below will use you're @ notation (@id, @ids) as a substitute 
   // to the verbs defined in your url (:userId, :otherid) respectively.
   // Sends POST /s2/param2
   resp.$save();

}, function(err) {
// Handle error here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource , you can only use suffixes, so no `s` or `param` prefix.

You could try to catch the parameters with just `:sid` and `:paramid`, and then trim that `s` and `param` part in your `User` constructor.

Comment: By the way, you seem more on the request side, so you should revert this. Use :suserId and fill it with the id prefixed with s